# $product->save() taking 4 seconds to save one simple product in magento 2.1.3

Tags: php, magento2

I have the code below with Image Upload which is working fine...But it takes 4 seconds to save one simple product... My store has more than 25 000 products. It takes more than 4/5 hrs to create/update the products... please, help...

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State'); 

$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

$_product->setName('Test Product');

$_product->setTypeId('simple');

$_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
$_product->setSku('test-SKU');

$_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));

$_product->setVisibility(4);

$_product->setPrice(array(1));

$_product->setImage('/testimg/test.jpg');

$_product->setSmallImage('/testimg/test.jpg');

$_product->setThumbnail('/testimg/test.jpg');

$_product->setStockData(array(

        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
    enter code here
        'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock

        'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart

        'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart

        'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability

        'qty' => 100 //qty

        )

    );

$_product->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

First things I would look at would be table corruption or table indexing